# Two VGA monitors off a single Mini DisplayPort

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga, external-display, microsoft-surface, mini-displayport

I have a surface tablet with dock. It has a single mini DisplayPort. I want to connect two VGA monitors.

I have heard that using a VGA splitter will work (sort of), but will result in the two screens mirroring themselves. This is obviously not what I want.

Can someone tell me
1. Can this be done?
2. If so, what adapters etc do I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick.
[Multi-Display MST Hub for Surface Tablets](https://www.accellcables.com/products/mini-displayport-1-2-to-2-displayport-multi-display-mst-hub) and also a HDMI to VGA cable.